# Django-filebrowser: no image preview on production server

Tags: django, image, preview, django-filebrowser

I installed django-filebrowser-no-grappelli. It work fine on django dev server. But on production server filebrowser didn't create preview images in admin (everything else works). PIL installed. All settings are default, as well as dev server. What's wrong? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed PIL on Pillow. It's working now.